# rpm tool can't be used in yocto enviroment

Tags: yocto, openembedded

In local.conf, I can see:

PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_rpm"

However, after boot the yocto OS, the rpm command not found.

Comment: Please take a look at the Yocto documentation: https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#runtime-package-management-build.  If you want to have these tools, you need to add 'package-management' to the IMAGE_FEATURES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PACKAGE_CLASSES` specifies the package manager the OpenEmbedded build system uses when packaging data. This will not add `rpm` package to your image.

To have `rpm` package to your image, add `EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES += "package-management"` to your `conf/local.conf`